# how executing laravel CRUD in one form

Tags: laravel

i am new in laravel , i have a simple form for Office Definition that want to read and so store and update and delete to the same form.
[image]

in my form, read and show data in table work correctly:

```
public function index()
    {
        $officesPaginated = Office::paginate(4);
        $offices=Office::where([['top_office_id',0],['status',1]])->get();

        return view('setting.office.index', compact('offices','officesPaginated'));
    }
```

And the DELETE method also works properly:

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>['office.destroy','office'=>$office->office_id],'method'=>'DELETE']) !!}
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"  style="width: 80px;height: 30px;">DELETE</button> 
 {!! Form::close() !!}
```

destroy method in controller:

```
public function destroy(Office $office)
    {
        $office->delete();
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

also onclick table call this function that filling blade tags including office_id tag that is disabled:

```
<script>
         function addRowHandlers() {
            var table = document.getElementById("tableId");
            var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
            for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var currentRow = table.rows[i];
                var createClickHandler = function(row) {
                return function() {
                    var cell1 = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];var id = cell1.innerHTML;
                    var cell2 = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[1];var caption = cell2.innerHTML;
                    var cell3 = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[2];var top_id = cell3.innerHTML;
                    var cell4 = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[3];var status = cell4.innerHTML;
                    
                    document.getElementById("office_id").value=id;
                    document.getElementById("caption").value=caption;
                    
                    document.getElementById("top_office_id").value=top_id;
                    document.getElementById("status").checked=!!parseInt(status);
                   
                };
              };
              currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
            }
          }
          window.onload = addRowHandlers();
    </script>
```

in blade this condition for store or update:

```
@if (isset($office))
    {!! Form::model($office, ['route'=>['office.update',$office->office_id],'method'=>'put']) !!}
@else
    {!! Form::open(['route'=>'office.store','method'=>'POST']) !!}
@endif
```

But in any case, the store method is executed,becuase $office not any value,I know that at the time of clicking on the table, I must set the value of the $office so that the editing method is executed, but how?
Maybe there is an alternative method that I can get a better result.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using JavaScript to dynamically change the form, i.e., its action attribute and method (POST for create, PUT for update) based on the row clicked. This way, you can avoid complexity and the rest will handled in server-side but requires you to change the Javascript implementation.

Comment: What exactly is your suggestion? How do I change my code?